# Docker Container volume bind's data not appearing in the volume

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume, docker-container, persistent-volumes

i'm trying to mount an existing directory that has images and subsequent images will be stored into it. I need to use that local directory to mount to a docker container.

When entering this command, it is successful, but there is no data inside. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you~!

```
docker volume create --name my_test_volume --opt type=none --opt device=/localdrive/myfolder/simplehttpserver/images --opt o=bind
```

Docker volume inspect

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2022-10-29T09:23:48Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/datadrive/docker/volumes/my_test_volume/_data",
        "Name": "my_test_volume",
        "Options": {
            "device": "/localdrive/myfolder/simplehttp/images",
            "o": "bind",
            "type": "none"
        },
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

I've tried to restart the docker daemon with sudo service docker but to no avail after creating the volume.

Doing a sudo ls in the directory volume directory in Docker directory

[sudo ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iIFF.png)

Comment: Show how you run the container. You need to specify the bind-mount to use when running it.

Comment: Bind mounts are not volumes. Volumes are not bind mounts. You don't create a bind-mount volume, you specify the directory to bind-mount when running the container.

Comment: @super hi, i hadn't create a container yet as what i thought initially was that the current images will be available in the new volume that i had created. Is that wrong?

Comment: @super hi! i managed to figure out my way through the difference between a bind mount and a volume.. Is it possible to create a docker volume with an existing folder in the local directory and run it in a seperate volume instead of in the local folder?

Comment: Sorry. Don't understand what you mean. A volume is something you mount into a running container. *run it in a separate volume* makes no sense.